# What is the meaning of the three numbers 741 in "openssl rand -base64 741"?

Tags: openssl

I'm creating an auth keyfile for mongodb and one way to do that is using: `/usr/bin/openssl rand -base64 741 > $TMPFILE`

I want to understand what is going on, I understood everything minus the meaning of three numbers 741

I couldn't find an explanation in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means it will use 741 bytes of random data and base64 it.

Example with `-hex 20` as this will be 40 long.

```
$ /usr/bin/openssl rand -hex 20
51b40b347dfccefa9b4f8a13d36c4564760c2f82
```

It is explained in the man page. See `num` at the end and the description:

```
SYNOPSIS
       openssl rand [-help] [-out file] [-rand file...]  [-writerand file]
       [-base64] [-hex] num

DESCRIPTION
   This command generates num random bytes using 
   cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator (CSPRNG).
```